# How to set a server that sends request to my API?

Tags: server, apache2, django

I am working with Linux, Ubuntu and an API made in Django.

My questions are:

1. How do I configure a server (preferably in apache) in order to send http requests to my API?
2. How do I 'catch' the data on my API?

Sorry if my questions are messy or unclear, I am fairly new in this domain.

Comment: Any tips on documentation that I should see for all the processes involved in this would be appreciated as well.

Comment: install mod_wsgi package for linux and add the package to httpd.conf then take a look on django docs to integrate wsgi with apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Long story short I created another simple API running on a different port.

I used:

1. POST method on API#1 with a simple submit button (json) and config to send it to the IP/PORT of the API#2
2. GET method on API#2 (result can only be see in the terminal, but that's all I needed)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I guess you are searching for a "reverse proxy" - have a look at the apache2 mod proxy:

```
ProxyPass "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
ProxyPassReverse "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
```

(https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apache:

```
    Option 1:

            -- sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils

    Option 2: latest one from the source code

            Steps:

                 Apache Tar file :

                    -- wget http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/httpd-2.4.20.tar.gz

                 Dependancy tar files:

                    -- wget http://www.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-1.5.2.tar.gz
                    -- wget http://www.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz
                    -- wget http://www.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-iconv-1.2.1.tar.gz

                 Before apache installation:

                    -- sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf gcc g++ libpcre3 libpcre3-dev

                 Unzip the apache tar files:
                         -- tar -xvf httpd-2.4.20.tar.gz
                         -- cd httpd-2.4.20/
                         -- Untar the "apr"(apr-1.5.2.tar.gz, apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz and apr-iconv-1.2.1.tar.gz) files
                         -- put it on httpd-2.4.20/srclib/ without version info

                 installing apache2 on /usr/local/apache2:

                 -- ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2
                 --  make
                 -- make install
                 -- Add "ServerName localhost" at conf/http.conf file
                 -- Change the listen port as whatever you want
```

mod_wsgi:

```
    -- Apache Requirements
            --Apache 2.0, 2.2 or 2.4

           -- wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.5.3.tar.gz
           -- tar -xvf 4.5.3.tar.gz
           -- ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-python=/usr/bin/python
           -- make
           -- make install
```

Apache configuration:

1) Create virtual environment
2) point that into vhost files
3) include vhost file inot httpd.conf file
    example:
        -- cd /usr/local/apache2/conf/
        -- sudo vim httpd.conf
        -- add the your vhost file location at end of the file
            My config goes like this: "include /home/kanagaraj/PycharmProjects/hyso_exchange/apacheconf/vhost.conf"

4) collectstatic( python manage.py collectstatice)
5) Pointout statice file into vhost file
6) type like this in your browser : http://localhost/

Note:
    example for vhost files vhost_local.conf , vhost_stating.conf